# Remove rows from table based on strings in column

Tags: r

I would like to remove rows from the table using the strings stored in the vector:

```
> dput(vec_temp)
c("HL", "LL", "ML")
```

Table looks like that:

```
structure(list(Accession = "AT1G71220", variable = structure(14L, .Label = c("f:HL-f:FL", 
"f:LL-f:FL", "f:ML-f:FL", "f:LL-f:HL", "f:ML-f:LL", "f:ML-f:HL", 
"m:HL-m:FL", "m:LL-m:FL", "m:ML-m:FL", "m:LL-m:HL", "m:ML-m:HL", 
"m:ML-m:LL", "ntrc:HL-ntrc:FL", "ntrc:LL-ntrc:FL", "ntrc:ML-ntrc:FL", 
"ntrc:LL-ntrc:HL", "ntrc:ML-ntrc:HL", "ntrc:ML-ntrc:LL", "WT:HL-WT:FL", 
"WT:LL-WT:FL", "WT:ML-WT:FL", "WT:LL-WT:HL", "WT:ML-WT:HL", "WT:ML-WT:LL"
), class = "factor"), value = 0.0445054204080209), .Names = c("Accession", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = 2167L, class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Names = c("35", "199", 
"363", "527", "691", "855", "1019", "1183", "1347", "1511", "1675", 
"1839", "2003", "2331", "2495", "2659", "2823", "2987", "3151", 
"3315", "3479", "3643", "3807"), class = "omit"))
```

Please focus on the column named `variable`. This table contains a single row with `variable` -> `ntrc:LL-ntrc:FL`. Looking at the vector from the begining of this thread we can see that `FL` was not there. Thus, I would like to remove that row (in general whole table). I would like to ask R to compare the strings from the vector with the strings stored in the column named `variable` which appear after `:`. If strings from table cannot be find in the vector the whole row (or table) should be removed.

Comment: So both `LL` and `FL` should be in the vector in order not to be deleted?

Comment: They should be in that vector at all. Order does not matter. As you see `FL` is not there.

Comment: You showed only a single row dataset.  Please include more rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to split the `variable` column and use `grepl` to identify whether the suffixes in the vector appear in the string **both** times (hence the `== 2`), i.e.

```
vec_temp <- c("HL", "LL", "ML")

i1 <- colSums(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$variable), '-', fixed = TRUE), function(i) 
                              grepl(paste(vec_temp, collapse = '|'), i))) == 2

df[i1,]
```

Comment: That sounds almost what I would like to achieve. Would it be possible to use the vector `vec_temp` instead of pasting specific strings ? That function will be applied in the loop so the strings may differ depending on the row. Additionally, I would like to know if it is applicable as well for the table with higher number of rows because it should ask if the strings appear in each of the specific rows in the table.

Comment: It will work with multiple lines Yes. Also temp vec is there